# Solr content search stops working after document update

Tags: java, solr, solrj

We upload PDF's with an added field "folder_id", which is set at upload. Content search works fine and we are able to filter using "folder_id" successfully.

However, we use a process similar to the below to update the "folder_id":

```
        String folderId = String.valueOf(folder.getId());
        HashMap<String, String> sFolder = new HashMap<>();
        sFolder.put("set", folderId);

        sDocument.addField("id", id);
        sDocument.addField("folder_id", sFolder);
        sclient.add(sDocument);
        sclient.commit();
```

Where the id is the unique id in solr. When this happens from what I can see all the fields remain t he same - however content search now will not work. I assume there is a disconnect between the tika index and solr after the update, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: What is the schema for the documents you're trying to update? If you're updating by sending a document to your Solr server without any special commands (i.e. atomic updates), only the fields you're sending will be included in the resulting document. Otherwise all fields _must_ be set as stored (or with `docValues` for those fields that support using the doc value as the stored value IIRC) to avoid losing the value for that field.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I am using set, which I believe is an atomic update. That's why I don't understand why content search isn't returning anything after the update - that shouldn't be removed.

Comment: I should also point out that even running a query on the extract text alone returns nothing. Is it possible that the extracted text is being removed somehow?

Comment: Using atomic updates _require all fields to be set as stored_. An atomic update is implemented as read the document, change the fields mentioned and then reindex it. If the content of the field can't be returned in its original form, it'll be lost.